# Using InDesign CS6 Server Scripting, Can I Hide a Specific Layer In A Document?

Tags: indesign-server

We have a system that allows users to fill in variable data in InDesign IDML files. As information is entered, an InDesign server renders a JPG of the IDML for user review. Once all data is entered, the user can then request a PDF (which is also rendered by the InDesign server).

We would like to allow the users to have a further level of customization by allowing them to choose between a few options for certain pre-determined content layouts. This content would be  included in the IDML file as separate layers.

Our current thinking is that we could add the optional content to the IDML files on different layers and as a part of the export process show/hide the layers based on the user's choices.

Is there a way to dynamically show or hide layers using the InDesign server scripting interface? The documentation is pretty sparse on what can be done.

Comment: I have found that I can usually get an answer to a question like this on the Adobe forums.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some detailed [automatically generated](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6serverjs_html/idcs6serverjs/about.html) documentation [here](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6serverjs_html/idcs6serverjs/) about the Adobe InDesign CS6 Server (8.0) Object Model.

In particular, [the page for `Layer`](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6serverjs_html/idcs6serverjs/pc_Layer.html) says that it has a read/write property called `visible`. This seems to be what you're looking for.

It looks like the path to get to the layer is something like this: `Application.Documents.firstItem().layers.itemByName('layerName')`.